# Make a MUI icon responsive

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, icons

I'm having some trouble making this MUI DeleteIcon responsive.

```
<ListItem>
   <ListItemAvatar>
      <Avatar src={sprites.front_default}>
         <ImageIcon />
      </Avatar>
   </ListItemAvatar>
   <ListItemText primary={name} />
   <DeleteIcon />
</ListItem>
<Divider variant="inset" component="li" />
<ListItem>
```

Basically, what I wanna do is make it clickable so that it takes me to another page, but I'm struggling to use the onClick function. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Place it inside an `IconButton`

```
<IconButton>
  < DeleteIcon /> 
</IconButton>
```